# What are the criteria for partial fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Consider the example of

> $$1\over (u^2 - 1)(u+1)$$.

$${Au + B\over u^2 - 1} + {C \over u + 1} = {Au^2 + Au + Bu + B + Cu^2 - C\over (u^2 - 1)(u+1)} = {1\over (u^2 - 1)(u+1)}$$

$$\begin {cases}A + C =0 \\ A + B = 0\\ B - C = 1\end{cases}$$

Adding $3$ and $1$,

$$\begin {cases}A + B =1 \\ A + B = 0\end{cases}$$

---

The degree of denominator is $3$ and that of numerator is $0$, so I should not have got inconsistent group of equations.

What are the criteria for partial fractions ? what am I missing in this example ?

Also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fraction%20%201%2F((u%5E2%20-%201)(u%2B1))) gives proper partial fraction of the following.

Comment: @Chappers Yes thank you. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change variables to make things clearer (won't affect the theory, of course). If we put $1+u=x$, the original fraction becomes
$$ \frac{1}{((x-1)^2-1)x}  = \frac{1}{(x^2-2x)x} = \frac{1}{x^2(x-2)}. $$
Now, your question boils down to what happens when we add two fractions
$$ \frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x(x-2)}. $$
But we can put them over the common denominator $x(x-2)$, so
$$ \frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x(x-2)} = \frac{Ax-2A+Bx+C}{x(x-2)} = \frac{(A+B)x-2A+C}{x(x-2)}!  $$
So *this* is the problem: no matter what polynomial we put on top of these fractions, they will *never* produce a denominator that is $x^2(x-2)$!

Okay, what about
$$ \frac{A}{x^2} + \frac{Bx+C}{x(x-2)}? $$
This looks better, since we have to put it over a common denominator $x^2(x-2)$. Then we get
$$ \frac{Ax-2A+Bx^2+Cx}{x^2(x-2)}. $$
Therefore we're forced to take $B=0$. We also have to get rid of the $x$ term, so $A=-C$. Then you can choose $A$ in order to get $-2A=1$, so
$$ \frac{-1/2}{x^2} + \frac{1/2}{x(x-2)} $$
*is* a valid partial fraction decomposition for $1/x^2(x-2)$ (and equally,
$$ \frac{-1/2}{(1+u)^2} + \frac{1/2}{u^2-1} = \frac{1}{(u+1)(u^2-1)}). $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As for as I understand from your answer, I can also take $$\frac{Bx+C}{x^2} + \frac{A}{(x-2)}$$ can I ?

Comment: Yes, and that is equivalent to the more usual form
$$ \frac{B}{x} + \frac{C}{x^2} + \frac{A}{x-2}. $$

Comment: Yes thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

sunce we have $$\frac{1}{(u^2-1)(u+1)}=\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)^2}$$ you must make the ansatz $$\frac{A}{u-1}+\frac{B}{u+1}+\frac{C}{(u+1)^2}$$

Comment: Why so ? $\qquad$

Comment: Also should not it be $${A \over u - 1} + {Cu + D \over u^2 + 1}$$ ?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: I think I got it. Both factor polynomials should not have any common factor ?

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$ f(u)=\frac{1}{(u^2-1)(u+1)}=\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)^2} $$
has a simple pole at $u=1$ and a double pole at $u=-1$. It follows that its partial fraction decomposition has the following form:
$$ f(u) =\frac{A}{u-1}+\frac{B}{u+1}+\frac{C}{(u+1)^2} $$
where $A$ can be found through
$$ A = \lim_{u\to 1}(u-1)\,f(u) = \lim_{u\to 1}\frac{1}{(u+1)^2} = \frac{1}{4} $$
and $C$ can be found through
$$ C = \lim_{u\to -1}(u+1)^2\,f(u)=\lim_{u\to -1}\frac{1}{u-1}=-\frac{1}{2}. $$
We have $A+B=0$ because $f(u)$ decays faster than $\frac{1}{u^2}$ at infinity, hence $B=-\frac{1}{4}$ and finally

> $$ f(u) = \frac{1/4}{u-1}-\frac{1/4}{u+1}-\frac{1/2}{(u+1)^2}. $$

Comment: How did you conclude partial fractions from the poles of the function ?

Comment: @A---B: I do not understand your question. The partial fraction decomposition depends on the behaviour of the given meromorphic function at its poles, what else?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my ignorance but I don't know anything about meromorphic function, nevertheless thanks for answer, I might revisit it after I know enough to understand the answer.